# Matching till one of alternative unescaped characters/sequences or a newline

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a string till a terminal character/sequence, where:

- The terminal character/sequence is not part of the match.
- The terminal character/sequence is one of a defined set, let's say `(',',':', '%%')`.
- Escaped terminal characters/patterns do not act as terminators.
- An escaped backslash is to be consumed and not used for escaping following characters.
- end of string also terminates the match, even if preceded by an escape character.
- newline characters `(LF,CR)` also act as terminators, even if preceded by an escape character. They are also not part of the match (but the last dangling escape if any, is).

So the core problem: some terminator sequences are neutralized by escapes others aren't.

These are some sample strings and their desired match results: the character sequences
are to be taken as raw, but I'm using `<newline>` for `(LF,CR)` (i.e for raw newlines as in `U+000A, U+000D`)

```
1: xxx\,aaa,bbb --> xxx\,aaa
2: xxx\\:aaa,bbb --> xxx\\
3: xxx\\\\\,aaa\::bbb --> xxx\\\\\,aaa\: 
4: xxx%%aaa --> xxx
5: xxx\%%aaa --> xxx\%%aaa
6: xxx%\%bbb\ --> xxx%\%bbb\
7: xxx\,aaa<newline>bbb --> xxx\,aaa
8: xxx\,aaa\<newline>bbb --> xxx\,aaa\

9: x\xa\a\,bb\\,bb --> x\xa\a\,bb\\
```

Following the style of some other questions here on SO, I managed to get to this:

```
pat = re.compile(r'.+?(?<!\\)(\\\\)*(?=[:,\n\r]|%%|$)', re.DOTALL|re.UNICODE)
```

But this doesn't cover all the rules, it has problems with escaped newlines and escaped end of string.

**Edit:**
A backslash can occur before any character without causing mismatch (see example 9), it's just that if it occurs before another backslash, it neutralizes its effect as an escape character, and if it occurs before certain terminators, it neutralizes their effect as terminators.

Answer (score 1):

This was really challenging. Here my approach:

```
import re

l = ['xxx\\,aaa,bbb',
 'xxx\\\\:aaa,bbb',
 'xxx\\\\\\\\\\,aaa\\::bbb',
 'xxx%%aaa',
 'xxx\\%%aaa',
 'xxx%\\%bbb\\',
 'xxx\\,aaa\nbbb',
 'xxx\\,aaa\nbbb',
 r'x\xa\a\,bb\\,bb']

for s in l:
    print('|||| {0} |||| --> {1}'.format(s, re.match(r'((?:(?:(?:\\\\)+|\\(?:,|:|%)|[^\\,:\n]|\\(?:[^\n]|$))(?<![^\\]%%))*)', s).group(0).rstrip('%')))
```

Some issues:

First, I don't understand your sixth string. How can you have a single backslash as last character of a string? It has no sense for me.

Second, I found very difficult to check a double percentage sign without escape any of them. Look-behind is useless because I can't know how many backslashes there will be, and neither look-ahead because it doesn't match the character just before them, so I used a workaround, that does a look-behind matching the first of the pair and remove it with `rstrip()`. Then it's not a pure `regex` (needed post-processing) but it was my limit.

Explanation of the most important pieces:

1. `(?:\\\\)+`  -- Advance every pair of backslashes.
2. `\\(?:,|:|%)` -- Advance any of your set of characters that is escaped.
3. `[^\\,:\n]`  -- General rule, any character but those that have special meaning for this case.
4. `(?<![^\\]%%)` --  Stop when found a non-escaped pair of `%`.
5. `\\(?:[^\n]|$)` -- Match a backslash followed by a non-special character or EOL.

I put the original string between pipes to note the newlines. Probably it doesn't match every possibility far of your examples but I hope that you get the idea. The previous script yields:

```
|||| xxx\,aaa,bbb |||| --> xxx\,aaa
|||| xxx\\:aaa,bbb |||| --> xxx\\
|||| xxx\\\\\,aaa\::bbb |||| --> xxx\\\\\,aaa\:
|||| xxx%%aaa |||| --> xxx
|||| xxx\%%aaa |||| --> xxx\%%aaa
|||| xxx%\%bbb\ |||| --> xxx%\%bbb\
|||| xxx\,aaa
bbb |||| --> xxx\,aaa
|||| xxx\,aaa
bbb |||| --> xxx\,aaa
|||| x\xa\a\,bb\\,bb |||| --> x\xa\a\,bb\\
```

Comment: re number 6: that's just a literal backslash, say you are reading from a file - don't see a problem.

Comment: @BaselShishani: But a literal backslash must be escaped too, as you wrote in your second or third example.

Comment: Can be used with any character, but has effect of neutralizing certain terminators or a following backslash. See my edit - thanks.

Comment: @BaselShishani: Updated the answer with your ninth case.

Answer (score 0):

**OP:**

Found a simple approach: enumerate all legal cases rather than trying to match terminators:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'([^,:\n\r%\\]|\\[^\n\r]|%(?!%)|\\(?=\n|\r|$))*', re.DOTALL)

patver = re.compile(r'''(
[^,:\n\r%\\]  | # generic: consume any non-special char
\\[^\n\r]     | # consume any escaped char - enc '%' and backslash
%(?!%)        | # two successive '%', no need for lookbehind because of previous term 
\\(?=\n|\r|$) | # dangling backslash
)*''', re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE)

l = [r'xxx\,aaa,bbb',
 r'xxx\\:aaa,bbb',
 r'xxx\\\\\,aaa\::bbb',
 r'xxx%%aaa',
 r'xxx\%%aaa',
 'xxx%\\%bbb\\',
 'xxx\\,aaa\nbbb',
 'xxx\\,aaa\\\nbbb',
 r'x\xa\a\,bb\\,bb',
 r'xxx\\%%bbb',
 r'xxx\%%%bbb',
     ]

for s in l:
    print('|||| {0} |||| --> {1}'.format(s, re.match(pat, s).group(0)))
```

This approach won't be practical for long terminator sequences.